# Class initialization - attribute has no default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, copy-constructor

I have two classes Bar and Foo

```
class Bar
{
  Foo attr;        
public:      
  Bar(int i);
}

class Foo
{
  std::string _name;        
public:      
  Foo(std::string name) : _name(name){}
}
```

The problem is that `Foo`has no default constructor but only one constructor that takes a `std::string`. moreover `operator=` is a private member of Foo. So how can I initialize `attr` so that its name will be `"good"` if `i==0` and `"bad"` otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You obviously know how to initialise members because you did so in `Foo`. What is preventing you from using the same technique to initialise `attr` in `Bar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a constructor initializer list:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(int i) : attr(i == 0 ? "good" : "bad") {}

private:
    Foo attr;
};
```

You should probably also make the `Bar` constructor `explicit` so that random integers don't accidentally get interpreted as `Bar`s in your code.